# How to change EJB timer thread pool size in TomEE/OpenEJB?

Tags: java, ejb, quartz-scheduler, apache-tomee, openejb

TomEE 1.6.0 has a default thread pool with 3 threads for EJB timer scheduling. I'd like to increase the size of this pool or configure a separate pool for my web application.

I've tried to set the following properties separately or together inside my application in `WEB-INF/application.properties` and for TomEE globally in `tomee/conf/system.properties` but they don't seem to have any effect:

```
openejb.timer.pool.size = 30
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 30
```

How can I increase the EJB timer pool thread count in TomEE?

Edit: I'm aware of [this blog post](http://rmannibucau.wordpress.com/2012/08/22/tomee-quartz-configuration-for-scheduled-methods/) which appears to give the answer and have tried to apply that with no success. I'd like to avoid a custom ThreadPool implementation and thought one of the above properties should suffice.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in a [TomEE Users mailing list thread](http://openejb.979440.n4.nabble.com/How-to-change-EJB-timer-thread-pool-size-td4669499.html), the property is currently `EjbTimerPool.CorePoolSize`. The fact that the other mentioned properties don't work in 1.6.0 is a regression which is now fixed in TomEE trunk and will be released in TomEE 1.7.0.

To set the EJB timer pool size to 30, for example, add this to tomee_home/conf/system.properties:

```
EjbTimerPool.CorePoolSize = 30
```

The [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.openejb/openejb-core/4.6.0/org/apache/openejb/core/timer/DefaultTimerThreadPoolAdapter.java#69) verifies the answer although an unused constant for openejb.timer.pool.size in the same class can be confusing.